# slice happens in the code but it doesnt update in the UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- there are three drop down menus in the initial state.
- after I select the first drop down the second drop down values gets loaded
- after I select the second drop down values.
- a new set of drop down loads.
- when I select remove button of the second set.
- it doesnt remove that set but it removes the first set.
- when I debugged removeSelectedValue method there slices are happening correctly but its not updating in the updating
- can you tell me how to pass the queryComponents values so that it will update in the UI.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my relevant code snippet and sandbox below.
- all my code is in demo.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9lw9qrmx

```
removeSelectedValue = index => {
    console.log("removeSelectedValue--->", index);
    let seletedValues = this.state.queryComponents;
    seletedValues.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("spliced Values--->", seletedValues);
    this.setState({ queryComponents: seletedValues });
  };

  render() {
    let queryComp = this.state.queryComponents.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <AutoCompleteComponent
          key={index}
          value={value}
          index={index}
          valueSelected={this.getSelectedValue}
          removeSeleted={this.removeSelectedValue}
        />
      );
    });

    return <div>{queryComp}</div>;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `let seletedValues = this.state.queryComponents;`
you're creating a reference to that variable, instead of making a copy.

You need to make sure you replace your state with a new object/array for the re-render to happen.

Please try this:

```js
removeSelectedValue = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        queryComponents: prevState.seletedValues.filter((a, i) => (i !== index));
    });
};
```

That filter function is equivalent to the splice you were using, but returns a new array instead of modifying the original one.

On the other hand, I 'm passing `setState` a function that uses `prevState` making the code shorter.

Comment: hey I updated your code in sandbox but still I am facing issues :( https://codesandbox.io/s/4x9lw9qrmx